# Executing PlaySpec tests with Scalatest from packaged binary

Tags: scalatest

I have a Play project with functional tests. I am able to execute the tests with SBT. They are testing with a browser against a deployed application, i.e. `with OneServerPerSuite with OneBrowserPerSuite ...`

Instead of executing the tests with SBT / from source, I'd like to compile & package them and run from binary. However, if I package the test classes (with `test: package` in SBT) and run them, no tests are executed, e.g. if I copy all dependencies to `libs` including scala, ScalaTest, etc:

```
$ java -cp target/scala-2.10/myproject-acceptance_2.10-1.0-tests.jar:libs/* org.scalatest.tools.Runner -o -u results
Discovery starting.
Discovery completed in 20 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 0
DiscoverySuite:
Run completed in 57 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 0
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
```

I can't get any tests to run. I have tried `-s`, `-m`, `-w`, `-q` switches for the scala test runner. The closest I can get to getting a test to run is by specifying a suffix (e.g. for "MyWebappLogin")

```
$ ... Runner -o -u results -q Login
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
```

The tests themselves are based on the guidelines from [Play - Scala Functional Testing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest)

Here's the Login test I was trying (`MyWebappLogin.scala`):

```
class MyWebappLogin extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite with OneBrowserPerSuite with PhantomJSFactory with MustMatchers {

  val loginPage = new WebappLoginPage() //extends org.scalatest.selenium.Page with WebBrowser

  "The Login Page" must {
    "Render with title" in {
      go to (loginPage)
      pageTitle mustEqual "Please Log In"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I go about getting the tests to run with the ScalaTest runner?

Comment: BehrouzMoslem its `ScalaTest` not `ScaleTest` - http://www.scalatest.org/